# Creating new aggregated R dataframes with a function in lapply

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create new aggregated dataframes from existing ones that are collected in a list. Ideally they would appear as their own dataframes indicated by a prefix. This is where I've got:

```
dfList <- list(A = data.frame(y = sample(1:100), x = c("grp1","grp2")),
               B = data.frame(y = sample(1:100), x = c("grp1","grp2")))

agrFun <- function(df){
    prefix <- deparse(substitute(df))
    assign(paste0(prefix,"_AGR"),
           aggregate(y ~ x, data = df, sum))
}

lapply(seq_along(dfList), function(x) agrFun(dfList[[x]]))
```

Aggregation happens as intended but I'm not sure what I need to do otherwise in order to create dataframes A_AGR and B_AGR.

EDIT:
A bit of clarification. I want to have the aggregated dataframes appear in the environment.

So instead of this

> ls()
>   [1] "agrFun" "dfList"

my goal is to have

> ls()
>   [1] "A_AGR" "B_AGR" "agrFun" "dfList"

EDIT2:

Or more ideal would be to have dfList include dataframes A, A_AGR, B and B_AGR after the process.

EDIT3:

And I also want to preserve the names of the dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way to do seems extremely complicated. You can create the wanted named `data.frames` in a `list` with this one liner:

```
setNames(lapply(dfList, function(u) aggregate(y~x, u, sum)), paste0(names(dfList),"_AGR"))

#$A_AGR
#     x    y
#1 grp1 2340
#2 grp2 2710

#$B_AGR
#     x    y
#1 grp1 2573
#2 grp2 2477
```

With your function `agrFun`:

```
lst = setNames(lapply(dfList, function(x) agrFun(x)), paste0(names(dfList),"_AGR"))
```

If you want to append the two lists:

```
dfList = append(lst, dfList)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the setNames(). However, my reproducible example was perhaps too simplistic. In my application I want to have several different aggregations in the agrFun function. So I still prefer solution where I have agrFun and one apply statement that produces all the aggregated dataframes.

Comment: you can always define something specific in the function into lapply ;) !

Comment: That still does not solve my problem. See clarification I included in the original post.

Comment: just ot mention it is a VERY bad R habit to full up the envrionment with various data.frames created on the fly, it is safer and cleaner to put it in a list.

Comment: If I could append the aggregated dataframes in dfList on the fly could be even better!

Comment: you mean you want to add to dfList the newly aggregated dataframes?

Comment: Exactly! That would be ideal.